# Inject functions to JSON data structure

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to inject functions to data structure created from JSON data using JavaScript prototype or another way? I have a rest service that returns list of contacts. The contact has firstName, lastName. I would like to add getFullName() function into each contact structure in a list.

I would like to do something like the following.

```
 var contacts = [{firstName: 'Stephen', lastName: 'Hawking'},
          {firstName: 'Nicolas', lastName: 'Tesla'},
          {firstName: 'Dean', lastName: 'Kamen'}
 ]; 
 for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
   var contact = contacts[i];
   //inject defined functions if it is not yet injected.
   //contact.inject(definedFunctions); //How do we do this
   console.log(contact.getFullName()); 
 }
```

Comment: What you're specifying above is just a js object, not a JSON. You can add a function to an object. You can't add a function to a JSON

Comment: http://www.json.org/ has all the types you can have, function isn't one of them

Comment: Edited my question "data structure created from JSON data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a wrapper around that data:

```
function Contact(data) {
  this.data = data;
}

Contact.prototype.getFullName = function () {
  return this.data.firstName + ' ' + this.data.lastName;
}

var contacts = [...]
  .map(function (data) {
    return new Contact(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to put functions in JSON data, because it is just text. Once you have parsed the JSON into JavaScript objects you can easily add properties to the objects that are functions:

```
for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
  var contact = contacts[i];
  contact.getFullName = function(){
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  };
  console.log(contact.getFullName()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "bind()":

```
var contacts = [{firstName: 'Stephen', lastName: 'Hawking'},
          {firstName: 'Nicolas', lastName: 'Tesla'},
          {firstName: 'Dean', lastName: 'Kamen'}
 ];
var getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};

 for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
   var contact = contacts[i];
   contact.getFullName = getFullName.bind(contact);
   // Or:
   //contact['getFullName'] = getFullName.bind(contact);
   console.log(contact.getFullName());
 }
```